# Flutter android app - android.support.v4.content.FileProvider not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Flutter android application,I want to download and write file but I got this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

so for solving above error  I add provider and xmlfile and its dependency but **now I got error that "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" is not found**

```
<application> 
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
     <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
</application




 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes I solved it**

I want to write file that's why I add `<provider></provider>` in manifest.But I write my file in simple way so I remove `<provider>` tag from there

And I write file using :

```
final response2 = await http.get(url);
var bytes = response2.bodyBytes;
var dirc = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/MyFiles");
if(dirc.exists()!=true){
  dirc.create();
}
File file = new File('${dirc.path}/$filename');
var newFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
await newFile.create();
if(newFile.exists() != null) {
  print("file create successfully");
  // showNotification  
}
```

> you should ask storage permission before write file